# Find all unit vectors in R^2 which are orthogonal to (−3, 1).

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The solution I came up with:

> Let $v = (a, b)$ be orthogonal to $(−3, 1)$. Note $\langle(a, b),(−3, 1)\rangle = 0$ or $−3a+b> = 0$; i.e. $b = 3a$. All unit vectors orthogonal to $(−3, 1)$ are of the form $||v||^{-1}(a , 3a )$.

The solution manual does mostly the same thing, but doesn't multiply a with $||v||^{-1}$. Instead it does:

> Choosing $a = 1$ and normalizing
>   gives $(1\sqrt{10},3\sqrt{10})$. Hence there are $2$ unit vectors orthogonal to $(−3,
> > 1)$ ; namely, $(1\sqrt{10}, 3\sqrt{10})$ and $(−1\sqrt{10}, −3\sqrt{10})$.

I don't understand why are there only two unit vectors? Couldn't we have chosen $a = 2, 3$, etc and produced more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the vectors orthogonal to $(-3, 1)$ are of the form $t(1,3)$ i.e. $(t,3t)$. However you need unit vectors, so their length should be $1$, which means that $t^2 + (3t)^2 = 1$. This is where $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ comes from.

Comment: but why did we chose a = 1 ? why couldn't we have done a = 2 too and gotten more unit vectors ?

Comment: @user40954 Of course I could have chosen another value of $a$ (not zero!) but the result would be the same. You can check it. Take a point $A$ and draw the line $l$ through it in the direction of the vector $(-3, 1)$. Then draw a line $m$ perpendicular to $l$ through $A$. Obviously if you draw the perpendicular vector starting from $A$ it should lie on $m$ and also the distance to it's end has to be exactly $1$. How many points can be the end of the vector?